# Python Pygame won't quit

Tags: python, pygame, exit

The code colors a pixel one by one and essentially prints a picture. I can't get it to quit though if I press the X to close or if I press Esc. I've put all the pg.event.get() code outside the main while loop, inside the main while loop, inside the secondary for loop, inside the tertiary for loop. I've ran it using IDLE and Spyder and same issue, no matter where I put it, I can't get it to quit. How can I get it to work????

```
loop = True
while loop:
    #Event Management for exiting the screen 
    for event in pg.event.get():
            keys = pg.key.get_pressed()
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                    loop = False
            elif keys[pg.K_ESCAPE]:
                    loop = False
    pg.event.pump()

    #Setup pixel transformation loop
    for i in range(0,463):
            for u in range (0,600):
                    screen.set_at((u,i),reddat[u,i]-greendat[u,i]-bluedat[u,i])
                    pg.display.flip()

    loop = False
```

Comment: You're running the whole of the pixel transformation in one go. There's no point in the middle of your for loops where they can break or detect the events. The easiest way to fix this is with a function to check for quit or escape events every time your *inner* for loop runs. Though I'm not sure that would be the best flow anyway as it may take an immensely long time (depending on how long it takes to check pygame's events).

Comment: ok, are you suggesting I don't run the pixel transformation in one go or just move the whole the event management inside the for loop? I have actually tried that and it hasn't worked :-{

Comment: Check out my edited answer. Also, maybe the title should be changed to "How to create an image build-up effect in Pygame" or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing the whole pixel transformation without checking for events. Here's your flow in pseudo code:

```
loop until break:

    check events
    loop through pixels
        transform pixels
    break
```

Instead, you should ditch the `while loop`, make `check_for_quit` a function and then put that function nested in your transformation loop.

```
def check_for_quit():
    """Event Management for exiting the screen"""

    for event in pg.event.get():
        keys = pg.key.get_pressed()
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            return True
        elif keys[pg.K_ESCAPE]:
            return True
    pg.event.pump()
    return False


def draw():
    """Setup pixel transformation loop"""

    for i in range(0,463):
        for u in range (0,600):
            if check_for_quit():
                return

            screen.set_at((u,i),reddat[u,i]-greendat[u,i]-bluedat[u,i])
            pg.display.flip()
```

Instead of using a while loop you can have `check_for_quit` return `True` or `False` to indicate whether or not to quit, and then you can test that in each loop and `return` to exit the loop early when it's over.

Note I don't work with pygame, so while this should work it might not be the best solution for running code while trying to check for events.

Comment: Whoops, i never check for other answers while i'm writing one. nvm

Answer (score 0):

During the pixel transformation loop you are not running the anything to detect events. You were on the right track about moving the loops about.

if you shift the event checking code into the pixel transformation loop you can poll events while generating the pixels

Example:

```
for i in range(0,463):
    for u in range (0,600):
        screen.set_at((u,i),reddat[u,i]-greendat[u,i]-bluedat[u,i])
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                break
            elif event.type == py.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == py.K_SPACE:
                    break
        pg.display.flip()
```

This removes the need for a while loop aswell.

Answer (score 0):

First, your event loop looks weird. I think you should use either `for event in pg.event.get():` or `keys = pg.key.get_pressed()` but not both.

I'm not sure if you just want to create a background surface or a build-up effect. Also, you should've explained what the variables `reddat`, etc. are.

If you just want a background image you only need to create a surface before the main loop, blit the pixels onto the surface and then blit it on the screen in the main loop.

Elif you want the build-up, you could use a generator to get the pixels and then use `itertools.islice` to get chunks of it. Here's an example of the build-up:

```
import sys
import pygame as pg
from itertools import islice


def generate_pixels(width, height):
    """Generate pixel coords for the build-up effect."""
    for i in range(height):
        for u in range(width):
            yield i, u


def main():
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    width, height = (640, 480)
    screen = pg.display.set_mode((width, height))
    pixels = generate_pixels(width, height)
    done = False
    while not done:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                done = True
            if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pg.K_ESCAPE:
                    done = True

        # Change the second arg of islice to adjust the speed.
        for i, u in islice(pixels, 2000):
            screen.set_at((u, i), (i % 256, u % 256, (i + u) % 256))

        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pg.init()
    main()
    pg.quit()
    sys.exit()
```

---

Edit: There's a simpler way to create a build-up effect: You can pass an `area` argument to the blit method of surfaces. So we can create the final image beforehand (or load one) and then just increase the percentage of the image that we want to blit on the display surface.

```
import sys
import pygame as pg


def main():
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    width, height = (640, 480)
    screen = pg.display.set_mode((width, height))
    # Create the final image beforehand.
    image = pg.Surface((width, height))
    for i in range(height):
        for u in range(width):
            image.set_at((u, i), (i % 256, u % 256, (i + u) % 256))
    image_percent = 0

    done = False
    while not done:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                done = True
            if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pg.K_ESCAPE:
                    done = True

        screen.fill((90, 10, 200))
        # Increase the displayed portion of the image.
        if image_percent < 100:
            image_percent += .5
        # The third argument is the area of the surface on which we'll
        # blit the image.
        screen.blit(image, (0, 0), (0, 0, width/100*image_percent, height))

        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pg.init()
    main()
    pg.quit()
    sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help, I did move the event loops into the for loop reorganised them by seperating the key event as below. This worked for me. Regarding the image, the goal of this was to display the image pixel by pixel soo that's why I blitted each loop. Anyway,Appreciate your comments. Next time I think a quit function would be very useful so will set one of them up.
Here's what worked for me

```
for u in range (0,600):
            for i in range(0,463):

                    screen.set_at((i,u),(reddat[u,i],greendat[u,i],bluedat[u,i]))
                    pg.display.flip()
            #Event Management for exiting the screen 
            for event in pg.event.get():
                    if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                            pg.quit()
                    keys = pg.key.get_pressed()
                    if keys[pg.K_ESCAPE]:
                            pg.quit()
            pg.event.pump()
```

Comment: Looks still pretty odd to me. I don't think `pg.display.flip` in a nested loop is a good idea. It's refreshing the display like crazy and one of your cpu cores will heat itself up quickly.